# Filter feature in the Google Sheets doesn't treat the exact word as a match when it is within the parenthesis?

Tags: google-sheets, filter

Filter feature in the Google Sheets doesn't treat the exact word as a match when it is within the parenthesis? This is not the case in the MS Excel sheet. Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

[image]

Comment: It's seems to work just fine See [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/YA4sXbO.png)

Answer (score 1):

you should use custom condition (contains):

[image]